# lostfocus in 3 elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my page

```
$("#ddlBirthdayDay,#ddlBirthdayMonth,#ddlBirthdayYear").change(function () {
    $("form").validate().element("#ddlBirthdayYear");
});
```

I need to change it to: I haven't the focus in the three input `$("#ddlBirthdayDay,#ddlBirthdayMonth,#ddlBirthdayYear")`, I validate the element in the form.

How can I do this in jquery??

Comment: You want to process both change & lost focus event don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your elements are in the same wrapper you could use `focusout`.
http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Together with the `:focus` selector.
http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

```
var focusTimer = null;
$("form").on("focusout", function(){
  clearTimeout(focusTimer);
  focusTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    var focusedElements = $("#ddlBirthdayDay,#ddlBirthdayMonth,#ddlBirthdayYear").filter(':focus');
    alert(focusedElements.length);
  }, 50);
});
```

Unfortunately you would need the set timeout as tabbing through the input fields would cause wrong results otherwise.

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EvfUT/)**

Comment: My need is to detect that i lostfocus in this 3 elements and the focus is outside of this 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute to each element to say it lost focus. Then when all elements have lost focus, fire the validate event for each:

```
var $elems = $("#ddlBirthdayDay,#ddlBirthdayMonth,#ddlBirthdayYear");
$elems.blur(function () {
// Add a flag to this element to say it's lost focus
$(this).attr("data-blurred", "true");
console.log("blurred");
// If the number of elements in total equals the number with the blurred flag...
if($elems.filter("[data-blurred]").length === $elems.length) {
     // Iterate over all the original elements and fire the validate event
     $elems.each(function() {
         $("form").validate().element($(this));
     });
} 
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/qST6q/).

Comment: blur will fire when i lostfocus in one of the three element, i need validate when i lost the focus of the 3 elements (when i go outside of this 3 inputs in the form).

Comment: $elems.find("[data-blurred]").length is always=0

Comment: it's ok, I have an other need, with this code, if i lost the focus in the 3 elements, I validate. I need to add order, if i lost focus in one of the element #ddlBirthdayDa and i go to other element different from #ddlBirthdayMonth,#ddlBirthdayYear, i validate

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
$(function(){
$('#a,#b,#c').on('blur',function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$('#a,#b,#c').is(':focus')) {
            alert('Lost focus on all controls');
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

});

Take a look at my demo: [Detect if controls lost focus](http://jsfiddle.net/b6KPj/)